# Cómo corregir Unhandled Exception dependOnInheritedElement() was called before method completed?

Tags: flutter

Estoy consultando a mi api para mostrar datos en una aplicación, pero aun no entiendo muy bien como se construyen los widgets y parece que el fallo viene por ahí, no me muestra dato alguno.

Mi código:

```
class LocalSinConexion extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LocalSinConexion createState() => _LocalSinConexion();
}

class _LocalSinConexion extends State<LocalSinConexion> {

  List<Locales> data = <Locales>[];

  Future<List<Locales>> tomar_datos() async{
    final arguments = (ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments ?? <String, dynamic>{}) as Map;
    var slug = arguments['slug'];
    var url = 'http://miweb/api/local-sin-conexion/$slug?api_key=key_cur_prod_fnPqT5xQEi5Vcb9wKwbCf65c3BjCCcCC';
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));

    var datos = jsonDecode(response.body);
    var registros = <Locales>[];

    registros.add(Locales.fromJson(datos));
    print(datos);

    return registros;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    tomar_datos().then((value){
      setState(() {
        data.addAll(value);
      });
    });
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Esto es el local'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: data.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
                return Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                  child: Text(
                      data[index].nombre
                  ),
                );
              }
            ),
          )
        ],
      )
    );
  }
}
```

La consola de AndroidStudio me devuelve lo siguiente.

> [VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<_ModalScopeStatus>() or dependOnInheritedElement() was called before _LocalSinConexion.initState() completed.
> When an inherited widget changes, for example if the value of Theme.of() changes, its dependent widgets are rebuilt. If the dependent widget's reference to the inherited widget is in a constructor or an initState() method, then the rebuilt dependent widget will not reflect the changes in the inherited widget.
> Typically references to inherited widgets should occur in widget build() methods. Alternatively, initialization based on inherited widgets can be placed in the didChangeDependencies method, which is called after initState and whenever the dependencies change thereafter.

En si el código no me da ningún error pero parece que comenta que al inicializar el widget con `initState()` no esta bien, o algo así comprendo yo.

También decir, que la consulta a la API trae siempre un único registro ya que solo traigo los datos del usuario que coincidan con el slug, posiblemente eso también lo este haciendo mal, adapte un código que tengo igual pero que si hacia falta hacer un `for`.

---

Parece que el fallo esta en esto:

```
final arguments = (ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments ?? <String, dynamic>{}) as Map;
```

Comenta que se llamo a esto antes de que se completara `_LocalSinConexion.initState().` pero no se como solventarlo

Alguna sugerencia??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como te decia en una de las respuestas pasadas, no creo que sea necesario que devuelvas un valor en la funcion `tomar_datos` porque es una función `asincrona` y el método `initState` no permite poner un `await`, para obtener el resultado de tu función, entonces puede que ahí esté el inconveniente, lo que te recomendaría hacer es:

```
    Future<void> tomar_datos() async{
        final arguments = (ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments ?? <String, dynamic>{}) as Map;
        var slug = arguments['slug'];
        var url = 'http://miweb/local-sin-conexion/$slug/api?api_key=key_cur_prod_fnPqT5xQEi5Vcb9wKwbCf65c3BjCCcCC';
        final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));

            if(response.statusCode > 199 && response.statusCode < 300) {
             var datos = jsonDecode(response.body);
             var registros = <Locales>[];
        
            registros.add(Locales.fromJson(datos));
            if(registros.isNotEmpty){
               data.clear();
               //actualización, segun tu edit solo devuelves un dato, ya no hace falta que hagas el for
               /*for(var i = 0; i< registros.length; i++){
                 data.add(registro[i]);
               }*/
             //Esto tienes que hacer:
             data.add(registro[0]);
                  }
                  print(data);
                 } else{
                  print('Ocurrió un error al hacer la consulta');
                  print(response.body);
              } 
          }
```

y en el `initState`:

```
     @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    tomar_datos();
  }
```

Comment: Hola @Jonathan Perez au no entiendo bien la construcción de las cosas. He probado lo que me comentas pero el error es exactamente igual. Amplie la pregunta para cometar que lo que recibe a través de la API es un único registro siempre, vamos que no hay que hacer un `for`

Comment: Si, yo también actualice mi respuesta

Comment: Actualice con lo que comentas, pero no le falta algún return o algo? no deja recargar la aplicación y da fallo en `_LocalSinConexion`

Comment: Puede que sea algún cierre de llave que me haya faltado, volví a actualizar el código, pero esta vez agregando un statudCode, para saber la respuesta del servicio

Comment: Nada sigue sin funcionar, es como si esa parte del código no se ejecutase

Comment: Cuando llamas a la funcion, que dato te imprime? la lista o el error?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137292/discussion-between-miguel-and-jonathan-perez).